# Django Database Routing

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having 3 databases defined in the Settings.py and routers for two apps in the respective app folders. When I try to run `manage.py migrate --database="app_db"` respectively for apps, it only runs `default` and second database list item. If I change the order of database list it won't perform the last one but only second one.

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django apps
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # my apps
    "cred",
    "dms",
    # third party apps
    "rest_framework",
]


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "databases/db.sqlite3",
    },
    "dms_db": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "databases/dms.sqlite3",
    },
    "cred_db": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "databases/cred.sqlite3",
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    "dms.routers.DMSRouter",
    "cred.routers.CredRouter",
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "cred.User"
CRED_DB_ROUTER = "cred_db"
DMS_DB_ROUTER = "dms_db"
```

if I put `dms_db` at list index 1 then it will migrate but `cred_db` won't. If I put `cred_db` at index 1 then it will migrate but `dms_db` won't.

Cred.Router.py

```
from django.conf import settings


class CredRouter:
    route_app_labels = ["auth", "cred", "contenttypes"]

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        return False
```

dms.router.py

```
from django.conf import settings


class DMSRouter:
    route_app_labels = [
        "dms",
    ]

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:  # noqa
            return settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:  # noqa
            return settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels  # noqa
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels  # noqa
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        return False
```

What I am running

Only `initial_0001.py` is there in migrations folder. So I guess? it is not making some issue. Not sure tho.

```
manage.py makemigrations 
manage.py migrate
manage.py migrate --database="cred_db"
manage.py migrate --database="dms_db"
```

All the models share this structure exactly.

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    ... 

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("organization")
        verbose_name_plural = _("organization")
```

As the project evolves we will be having more databases connections as we will be integrating our existing Django apps and each has a dedicated databases server already established. So this project will be connecting to at min 8-10 different databases. Manually migrating each by moving will be a issue for so many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Router works for **all the databases**, hence `allow_migrate` in `DMSRouter` is called for **both** `dms_db` and `cred_db`. Since `DMSRouter` only allows tables to be migrated to only `dms` app then your other apps tables are never migrated. What you need to do is use the argument `db` passed in the `allow_migrate` method and if it is not the one the router is dealing with then `return None` instead of `False`:

**Cred.Router.py**:

```
class CredRouter:
    route_app_labels = ["auth", "cred", "contenttypes"]

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER
        else if db == settings.CRED_DB_ROUTER:
            return False # Only apps in `route_app_labels` will be migrated to `cred_db`
        return None # Let other routers decide
```

**dms.router.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings


class DMSRouter:
    route_app_labels = [
        "dms",
    ]

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:  # noqa
            return settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:  # noqa
            return settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels  # noqa
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels  # noqa
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER
        else if db == settings.DMS_DB_ROUTER:
            return False # Only apps in `route_app_labels` will be migrated to `dms_db`
        return None # Let other routers decide
```

Comment: I was hoping for you to answer, searched for some twitter handle so I could DM you the question but couldn't find one. Never mind. Thank you so much.